# XML XInclude looses namespace in included nodes

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xinclude

I'm trying to use namespaces on a *xml* file composed by more files.

## XML Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    version="1.0"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="urn:mynamespace"
    targetNamespace="urn:mynamespace">

    <xsd:element name="main_element" type="typeMainElement" />

    <xsd:complexType name="typeMainElement">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="inner_element" type="typeInnerElement" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="test_attribute" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="typeInnerElement">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

## Main XML

```
<main_element test_attribute="value"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xmlns="urn:mynamespace">
    <inner_element>
        <description>Test</description>
    </inner_element>
</main_element>
```

Validating the *XML* with the *XML Schema* works perfectly.
But if I try to outsource some part of the *XML*, relying on `XInclude` then nothing works anymore.

## Splitted XML

```
<main_element test_attribute="value"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xmlns="urn:mynamespace">
    <xi:include href="simple_part.xml" />
</main_element>
```

## Included XML

```
<inner_element>
    <description>Test</description>
</inner_element>
```

Trying to validate the *Splitted XML* returns the error:

> simple_part.xml:1: element inner_element: Schemas validity error : Element 'inner_element': This element is not expected. Expected is ( {urn:mynamespace}inner_element ).
>
> simple_main_element.xml fails to validate

It seems that when *including* I loose the namespace inheriting, so the included content doesn't have a namespace anymore.

#### -- How do I solve this, without adding namespace prefixes everywhere? --

#### -- ADDED QUESTION: how to solve the problem also in the case where the inclusion is from another directory, like `<xi:include href="subdir/simple_part.xml" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that you have a few modifications to perform:

1) In your XML fragment, you need to declare the same namespace as as the "master" document

```
 <inner_element xmlns="urn:mynamespace">
   <description>Test</description>
 </inner_element>
```

2) In the resulting document, an `xml:base` attribute is automatically set [(see XInclude spec, §4.5.5 and C.1)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/) so that you have to declare it in your schema  by declaring this attribute and importing the `xml` namespace like so:

```
   <xsd:schema
       version="1.0"
       attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns="urn:mynamespace"
       targetNamespace="urn:mynamespace">

       <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd" />

       <xsd:element name="main_element" type="typeMainElement" />

       <xsd:complexType name="typeMainElement">
           <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="inner_element" type="typeInnerElement" />
           </xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:attribute name="test_attribute" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
       </xsd:complexType>

       <xsd:complexType name="typeInnerElement">
           <xsd:sequence>
               <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
           </xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:attribute ref="xml:base"/>
       </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:schema>
```

### Alternative solution with entities

You need to declare (parsed) entities in a DOCTYPE at the beginning of the "master" document, and use the reference instead of the `<xi:include>` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE main_element [
  <!ENTITY simple_part SYSTEM "simple_part.xml">
]>
<main_element test_attribute="value"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns="urn:mynamespace">
   <!-- call a reference instead of xi:include -->
   &simple_part_1;
</main_element>
```

The simple_part.xml will be exactely what you required in the original post:

```
<inner_element>
  <description>Test</description>
</inner_element>
```

Comment: yes it does. I was already able to solve it adding the namespace indeed. The solution is ok but I want to _avoid the additional `xml:base` attribute into the the schema_ (in my opinion that's not something related to the date definition but just a workaround that add dirtiness [am not blaming you; I know that's the common solution ;) ]). Anyway I added a question relative to the inclusion URI, if you want to expand your answer.

Comment: @Kamafeather It just came to my mind: if you don't want to modify your schema, perhaps you can use a good old entity reference?

Comment: I didn't get what an entity reference can do for me -_-'

Comment: @Kamafeather I haved added the "entity" solution to my answer.

Comment: Oh thanks, now I got it. Even if it doesn't suit my case (I solved just manually removing the `xml:base` attribute, cause in my context will not be needed). But good to know anyway!.